# How to link against system libraries and not Matlab's provided libraries

Tags: linux, matlab, linker, static-linking, rhel7

We have Matlab R2017a installed on a RHEL 7.3 machine and I can provide verbose installation instructions if necessary. We have the Matlab library paths saved in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/matlab.conf` and have run `ldconfig` to make sure the paths get picked up. Matlab works and everything is functional. However, Matlab seems to come bundled with it's own versions of libraries such as `libstdc++`, `libicui18n`, and others.

I'm trying to build and link a non-Matlab executable with the two libraries mentioned above and it's linking against Matlab's and not the system. How can I tell the linker to use the system provided libraries? I'm pretty sure this isn't a Matlab-specific problem, but that happens to be the environment I'm working in. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what our `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/matlab.conf` file looks like. Based on some testing, it does look like all three of these are necessary.

```
/opt/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64
/opt/MATLAB/R2017a/runtime/glnxa64
/opt/MATLAB/2017a/sys/os/glnxa64
```

There are libraries installed in the `runtime` that depend on libraries installed in `sys/os`. The libraries in `sys/os` are the ones conflicting with the RHEL system libraries (such as `libstdc++`).

Comment: Does Malab not separate its libraries from its system library replacements? Or are they in the same directory?

Comment: It does separate them. However, for example, `libstdc++` is located in both `/usr/lib64` and `/opt/MATLAB/R2017a/sys/os/glnxa64` with the latter path being defined in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/matlab.conf`.

Comment: I meant the desired Matlab libraries (e.g. libmatlab) and the ones it bundles (e.g. libc++). Are those in the same directory? In other words, is it a single directory you added to ld.so.conf?

Comment: Ah, sorry for misunderstanding, we have three paths added to the `ld.so.conf` where Matlab saves it's shared objects. All of which are under `/opt/MATLAB/R2017a` though.

Comment: Are all three necessary? Note that providing more information in the question would help to avoid this back-and-forth. The contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/matlab.conf` and a listing of those directories would be helpful. I'm trying to see if you really need the directory with Matlab"s libc++ in the ld path.